# Firebase hosting exception on rewrites property

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

In Firebase I wan't to route all URLs, except "/docs", to index.html

But it's not working. The exception is not considerated. All URLs are routing to index.html.

Thats my firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "target",
    "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/docs",
      "destination": "/docs.html"
    },{
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*",
        "headers": [
          {"key": "X-Content-Type-Options", "value": "nosniff"},
          {"key": "X-Frame-Options", "value": "DENY"},
          {"key": "X-UA-Compatible", "value": "ie=edge"},
          {"key": "X-XSS-Protection", "value": "1; mode=block"}
        ]
      },

      {
        "source": "**/*.@(css|html|js|map)",
        "headers": [
          {"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "max-age=3600"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false
  },

  "rules": "./firebase.rules.json"
}
```

And that's my "target" folder

[image: target folder]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I just needed to wait configurations to refresh.. I checked now and it is working..